# Run jar in a bash script can't create files but if I run jar en terminal it create files normally

Tags: java, linux, bash

When I run in terminal

> sudo java -jar -Xdebug
>   -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 MyJar.jar

It works perfectly but when I  call it in a bash script

```
case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR ~/Desktop/myservice.log  2>&1 &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
    ;;
```

it  fails!!

Comment: Isn't it a matter of permissions? Your direct java call uses `sudo`. Can you run your bash script with `sudo` too?

Comment: It fails how? It could be a classpath problem. Does that jar contains all the dependencies?

Comment: The jar has all dependencies and yes, I can run with sudo the bash script, in my jar I'm creating a .txt file, But when i run the bash script the file Is not created